# how to install jigdo tool in debian 10

Tags: debian, software-installation, dvd, mirror

I wanted to download all   DVD images of Debian and create a local mirror for installation in virtual machines etc in my USB hard disk.
So I started reading on internet and came to know that to download all kind of DVD CD images of Debian jigdo tool is a good option. Some how I read 
https://www.debian.org/CD/jigdo-cd/
original developer of jigdo 
http://atterer.org/jigdo/
now current developer of jigdo 
https://www.einval.com/~steve/software/jigdo/
he mentions on his website

> If you're a Linux user, then Jigdo is available for normal package
>   installation in Debian, Ubuntu and various other Linux distributions
>   too. That's normally the best way to get things. In case that's not an
>   option for you, (e.g. you need a newer version), then it should be
>   easy to build from source - see below.

current releases of jigdo 
https://git.einval.com/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=jigdo.git;a=summary
I was not able to understand how to download and install it on my Debian Virtual machine. 
I try to do an

```
debian@debian:~$ sudo apt-get install debian
[sudo] password for debian: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package debian
debian@debian:~$ sudo apt-get install jigdo
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package jigdo is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'jigdo' has no installation candidate
debian@debian:~$ sudo apt-get install jigdo-lite
[sudo] password for debian: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package jigdo-lite
debian@debian:~$
```

What have I missed here?
I could not understand from above pages how to download and install jigdo tool on Debian. What should I do /rather the question is how should I proceed?
Torrents are blocked in my country so if some other way to download all Debian images?

Comment: I strongly recommend not to use this tool. It is outdated and needs the defective `genisoimage` that is dead (unmaintained) since 15 years and that creates buggy filesystem images. This is a concept from the times of a slow internet.

Answer (score 2):

[Searching for "jigdo" in the packages list](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=jigdo&searchon=names&suite=stable&section=all) finds [jigdo-file](https://packages.debian.org/buster/jigdo-file), so you should be able to use `sudo apt-get install jigdo-file` or `sudo apt install jigdo-file`.

Just a note: the Debian documentation now suggests using `apt` as the primary front-end for installing packages over `dpkg` or `apt-get`.

[Manipulating Packages with dpkg](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-handbook/sect.manipulating-packages-with-dpkg.en.html#id-1.8.8.5) says:

> dpkg should be seen as a system tool (backend), and apt as a tool closer to the user, which overcomes the limitations of the former. These tools work together, each one with its particularities, suited to specific tasks.

and [aptitude, apt-get, and apt Commands](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-handbook/sect.apt-get.en.html) says:

> APT is a vast project, whose original plans included a graphical interface. It is based on a library which contains the core application, and apt-get is the first front end — command-line based — which was developed within the project. apt is a second command-line based front end provided by APT which overcomes some design mistakes of apt-get.